# How do I extract the name of a function from within a function in Python?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a function which I have defined:

```
def command("filename", function, error):
```

For 'function' I can input one of the following two functions:

```
def linear:
    return x

def exponential:
    return e**x
```

I want to save the figure under a name depended on the function used. So the name of figure will be something like this: `filename_function.jpg`

The command for this is `plt.savefig(filename_+????+'.png')`

How do I input the name of the specific function used into saved file?

So if my command is `command("hello.txt", linear, error)`, then my save file should read `hello_linear.png`.

Update: Thanks everyone. I am new to Python, and I guess I caught myself tied up in nonsense approaches to something that can be implemented very simply. The answer is `function.__name__` exactly as written.

Comment: `function.__name__` in the caller?

Comment: `linear.__name__` should give you the function name

Comment: -1 for no research effort whatsoever.

Comment: I don't know why people seem to be so upset with this question. IMO it's good and legit. The need arises from the attempt to avoid some (minor) code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are objects and have attributes: Simply use `function.__name__`.

Comment: If I understand the question, OP wants to know how to access `function` from within that very function.

Answer (score 1):

Using the magical [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module:

```
def foo():
    return inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name

foo()
=> 'foo'
```